# Declaring empty collections in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

How can i declare an empty collection for `mapOf`,`listOf` and `setOf` in **Kotlin**?

I have declared below variables:

```
val occupations = mapOf(Pair("Malcolm", "Captain"), Pair("Kaylee", "Mechanic"))
val shoppingList = listOf("catfish", "water", "tulips", "blue paint")
val favoriteGenres = setOf("Rock", "Classical", "Hip hop")
```

I want to check is these collection are empty or not.

Comment: All of these collections have an `isEmpty()` method, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: how to declare an empty collection that i am looking for

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> I want to check is these collections are empty or not.

Why can't you simply use the `isEmpty()` method?

```
print(occupations.isEmpty())    // >>> false
print(shoppingList.isEmpty())   // >>> false
print(favoriteGenres.isEmpty()) // >>> false
```

---

Anyway, if you really want to declare an empty collection, you can do it like this:

```
val emptyList = listOf<String>()
val emptySet = setOf<String>()
val emptyMap = mapOf<String, String>()
```

**OR**

```
val emptyList = emptyList<String>()
val emptySet = emptySet<String>()
val emptyMap = emptyMap<String, String>()
```

---

Let's take a look under the hood. Method `listOf()` called with no arguments has the following implementation:

```
/** Returns an empty read-only list.  The returned list is serializable (JVM). */
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun <T> listOf(): List<T> = emptyList()
```

It's easy to see that it simply calls another method - `emptyList()`:

```
/** Returns an empty read-only list.  The returned list is serializable (JVM). */
public fun <T> emptyList(): List<T> = EmptyList
```

that returns an **internal object** named `EmptyList`:

```
internal object EmptyList : List<Nothing>, Serializable, RandomAccess {
    // <...>
}
```

So the summary is that (as [@brescia123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1080191/brescia123) said) these methods do exactly the same thing: both of them return an empty immutable `List` and it's up to you to decide which one to use.

Comment: Thanks for your last edit i am searching for that whats the main difference

Comment: "in the first case you get mutable collections" - are you sure it is not the other way around?

Comment: `listOf<String>()` and `emptyList<String>()` are exactly the same: the first one just call the second one!

Answer (score 5):

You can create empty collections like this:

```
val occupations = mapOf<String, String>()
val shoppingList = listOf<String>()
val favoriteGenres = setOf<String>()
```